# removing content from text input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the code, which one i started. Issue is, after user focus out from the text input, i want to reset the text input. I mean what ever user enter to that field, i want to remove that.

```
$(function(){
        var field = $('#searchField');
        field.focusin(function(){
            console.log('element is focused.'); 
            field.animate({width: '100px'});
        });

        field.focusout(function(){
            console.log('element is not focused.');
            field.animate({width: '50px'});
            field.value = ''; // this is not working.
        });
    });
```

html code:

```
<p><input id="searchField" type="text" width="50px"/></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use `value` property of javascript `DOM` object with jQuery object. You need to use jQuery **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to get the value of jQuery object or convert jquery object to DOM object to use `value`.

```
field.value = ''
```

To

```
field.val(''); //using jQuery object
```

or

```
field[0].value = ''; //using javascript object
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
field.val('');
```

instead of

```
field.value = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easy :

```
$(function(){
    var field = $('#searchField');
    field.focusin(function(){
        console.log('element is focused.'); 
        $(this).animate({width: '100px'});
    });

    field.focusout(function(){
        console.log('element is not focused.');
        $(this).animate({width: '50px'});
        $(this).val(''); // This should work
    });
});
```